# ClipBoardManager Android .... NoClassdefFoundException

Tags: android, clipboard

I'm developping an android application, and a need to copy text (from listView item) to the clipboard in order to paste it in an editText.

So copy function looks like :

```
 ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
 clipboard.setText("String to copy");
```

However, an exception is fired on the first line :

```
04-12 15:08:59.101:
E/AndroidRuntime(25406): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.content.ClipboardManager
```

I've googled it, but i found no working answers.

Thanks for replies

Comment: I cannot replicate this error on a 2.2 emulator can you give me nor information on your environment and anything else that might be helpful?

Comment: Well, i'm developping on Galaxy S 2.3.3 Gingerbread.
My project is for API 15 (minimum 7).

Comment: I have this same problem

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the deprecation of the ClipboardManager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the package of ClipboardManager.

One is from android.text package, and the other is from android.content package.

android.content.ClipboardManager is only available on API level 11 and up. I am guessing thats the reason for this error.

So, you for running your code on older phones, you should use android.text.ClipboardManager

Comment: I've checked That, but this is my import :
import android.content.ClipboardManager;

So should i use the package coming from android.text ?

Comment: I tested with android.text.ClipboardManager (always with my Galaxy S), and this call : getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
returns null everytime.

Comment: I am also having this problem and have tried `ClipboardManager` from both packages. Neither works in an emulator or on my test device.